# Using Amazon RDS while having your application running on-premises. Makes sense?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm interested in taking advantage of Amazon's managed database (RDS), but, at the same time, I'd like my web application to run on-premises or on another cloud provider that offers data centers near me (less latency, as my application not always has to fetch data from the DB).

Is this scenario common? Would it make sense, or is Amazon RDS supposed to be run with instances running in Amazon?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to reduce latency this is probably not your best option, as DB performance is going to be pretty bad (very large latencies between the web application and the DB server, basically cancelling out and advantages of having the app server as close to your clients as possible).

I've actually had to test a similar configuration, with a DB server in Europe and an app server in the US and the performance was much worse than having both in any of the two regions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Did you have any concrete numbers of this decrease in performance? Any other side effect of the Europe-US config?

Comment: I don't have any numbers, as my particular application was pretty heavy in DB queries and this configuration rendered it unusable so we didn't go any forward in testing it.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently moved the database for our web application to RDS whilst still having our application servers hosted on-premise. Eventually the entire application will live on AWS, but it was too big a move to do all components at the same time. I'm only dealing with latency between Perth and Sydney in Australia, which is about 50ms, and this is working fine for us.

I don't recommend that you adopt this as a permanent configuration. You'll get much better performance from hosting your entire stack at AWS as opposed to keeping parts separated.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Did you notice any decrease in performance (even if not that big). Any other side effect of this move? Do you consider this configuration harder to maintain?

Comment: I'd consider performance to be better, but I did have to reengineer a lot of scripts to reduce the number of SQL queries being run. It is better to run three large queries than 10000 small queries (in a loop, for example). It would definitely be easier for the whole app stack to be hosted in AWS.